# how to solve this could not be converted to string with php?

Tags: php, object

this error occur when i convert object data to string

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class OfxParser\Entities\SignOn could
>   not be converted to string

vardump version is here

```
     object(OfxParser\Ofx)#4 (6) 
             { ["Header"]=> NULL ["SignOn"]=> object(OfxParser\Entities\SignOn)#5 (4) 
                     { 
                              ["status"]=> NULL ["date"]=> object(DateTime)#10 (3) 
                              { ["date"]=> string(26) "2007-10-15 02:15:29.000000" 
                              ["timezone_type"]=>int(3)imezone"]
                              =>string(13)"Europe/Berlin"} 
                               ["language"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (1) 
                               { [0]=> string(3) "ENG" } ["institute"]=> NULL 
                     } 
                       ["SignupAccountInfo"]=> array(0) { }  ["BankAccounts"]=>array(1) 
                      { [0]=> NULL } ["BankAccount"]=> NULL ["Investment"]=> NULL 
           }
```

i want to print like this

status  =   NULL

date    =   2007-10-15 02:15:29.000000

language =  ENG

Comment: why not just store the values of the object in variables outside the object and then concatenate those values into the string you want? Also, we can't give much more than suggestions without seeing exactly how you use your code (and not just a vardump)

Answer (score 0):

Try this , hope it will work

```
foreach($object as $objectValue){
         foreach($objectValue["SignOn"] as $objectParkey => $objectParValue){
              echo $objectParkey. '='. $objectParValue;
         }
}
```